# best location for features related theming customizations

Tags: 7, theming, features

The following is a simplified scenario of an organizational problem I'm facing.

I have a site with a single `features` module which handles all my content types. My `features` module is called `foo` and my `zen` subtheme is called `bar`.

One of my content types (e.g `event`) needs a special class on it so I have 2 options.

Add the class via the `foo.module`:

```
function foo_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  if ('event'==$vars['type']) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = "extra-class";
  }

}
```

or add the class via the `template.php` of `bar` theme:

```
function bar_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  if ('event'==$vars['type']) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = "extra-class";
  }

}
```

Which one of the two is the best location for this theme related customization? Without the `feature` there will be no `event` content type. So it feels like placing the code in the `feature` module file together with the content types is the best place.

On the other hand this css class is theme related so it also feels correct to place it in the `template.php`.

Comment: You might find that after a while your monolithic feature becomes quite large (full of these kinds of customisations) and difficult to split up (eg. if you want to use some of the content types in another site, but not all). I've personally found using a number of smaller features (eg. one per content type) to be more convenient, YMMV.

Comment: @Andy: Interesting. I will definitely consider in a next D7 project. The question still holds though even if I only had 1 content type in the feature.

Comment: oh yeah, was just digressing completely :) I agree 100% with Clive, classes are part of markup that _can_ be targeted by CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my opinion...

The HTML class itself is not related to the theme, it's related to the module defining the element on which it's placed (if it is a feature specific class name as @barraponto points out in the comments).

The *styling* for elements with that class is the theme's responsibility.

I would suggest that your code would be more appropriate inside the feature module. If it's not, imagine what will happen if you change themes...you'll lose the class that was on that element, meaning it can no longer be targeted for styling.

Comment: Classes aren't CSS, they're HTML. Therefore they should be meaningful. A `red` class shouldn't be set by the module (nor by the theme), but a `signup-closed` is clearly feature-specific and will benefit from being set by the feature itself.

Comment: @barraponto Yep good point, I've changed the answer a bit